# Web Sphere MQ 8.0 not connecting from home while same connects in office well

Tags: networking, tcp, ibm-mq

While I try to connect WMQ 8.0 from Home , It gives me error and getting failed while same Queue manager connects perfectly while I connect from office.

Queue manager name with host and port : MB8QMGR on '192.168.26.128(2414)'
Below is the error connection.

Could not establish a connection to the queue manager - reason 2538(AMQ4059).

kindly suggest me what's wrong with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you're not already aware, MQ Return Code 2538 is [MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q045380_.htm). This means that you have not managed to make the TCP/IP connection to your queue manager.

This is really a networking question rather than specifically an MQ question. Your question shows the IP address of the queue manager being a 192.168 address. This is a [private network address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network). This means you can't connect to it from outside that network. You'll probably find that you have 192.168 addresses at home as well, but that does not mean you are on the same network.

My understanding is that even with a VPN getting you inside you company network, you still need a real IP address to connect to, but someone with more experience of private networks may be able to confirm. Talk to your network people at work and ask them how you should connect to the server your queue manager is on, from home. Once you can TCP/IP ping it successfully, then attempt to an MQ connection.